# how to modifying the appearance of a JScrollPane in JAVA?

Tags: java, jscrollpane, appearance

how to modifying the appearance of a JScrollPane in JAVA?
I would like the JScrollPane only be one line. Something like Sublime Text

Comment: Take a look at the [Scrollable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface. This determines the size of movement that the scroll pane will move the view

Comment: when you say appearance here i think you mean the size, then @MadProgrammer is right, but if you want its width to be reduced you should look at themes.